# Carmichael numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Why do Carmichael numbers prevent Fermat's Little Theorem from being a guaranteed test of primality? Fermat' Little theorem works for any $a$ such that $1≤a\lt p$, where $p$ is a prime number. Carmichael numbers only work for $a$'s coprime to $N$ (where $N$ is the modulus). Doesn't this mean that for some non-coprime $a$ the Carmichael number will fail the test? Therefore if every $a$ is tested, a Carmichael number wouldn't pass.

Comment: Google (weak) probable prime and pseudoprime and then let us know if you stll have a question.

Comment: @Farhad Yusufali: Perfectly correct.  But if we view the matter probabilistically, it may be that numbers between $1$ and $m-1$ that are not relatively prime to $m$ are rare, so a test that relied on bumping into such a number would be impractical.

Comment: If $a$ is composite and not Carmichael then the proportion of $a \bmod m$ such that $a^{m-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod m$ is at least $50\%$, which is substantial. But if $a$ is composite and Carmichael then the proportion of $a \bmod m$ such that $a^{m-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod m$ can be very small; in fact the only such $a$ are *precisely* those sharing a common factor greater than 1 with $m$, so finding them randomly amounts to finding a factor of $m$ randomly. For instance, if $m = 294409$ then the proportion of $a \bmod m$ such that $a^{m-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod m$ is $4.9\%$.

Comment: If you think testing every $a$ is a good idea, then you can ignore all nonobvious math and just do trial division.

Comment: @KCd - I am obviously not going to test every $a$ - that would be trivial. I was just curious why the test would fail IF you tested every $a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal of the Fermat Primality test is to guarantee that a number is prime, then testing against all possible $a$ is no better than simply trying to divide our number by all primes.

In particular, if it were easy to find a number that is not coprime to $n$, then it's easy to factor $n$ and so we wouldn't need to use any sort of Fermat primality.

But you are correct. Notably, if $p | n$, then doing the test$\mod p$ would yield $0$.

Answer (score 6):

In case you looked at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) on Carmichael numbers, your question may have resulted from the sentence "Since Carmichael numbers exist, [the Fermat] primality test cannot be relied upon to prove the primality of a number". This is a bad formulation, since the Fermat primality test isn't meant to be used as proof of the primality of a number, but as a probabilistic test that is very likely to prove the compositeness of any composite number. It's that latter use that Carmichael numbers interfere with. As the article on the [Fermat primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) shows, for numbers $n$ other than primes and Carmichael numbers, at least half of all numbers coprime to $n$ are Fermat witnesses, i.e. let the test prove compositeness. Thus the Fermat primality test serves its function well for non-Carmichael numbers, whereas for Carmichael numbers with relatively high prime factors, such as $8911=7\cdot19\cdot67$, the probability of proving compositeness with a randomly chosen number $\lt n$ is significantly reduced (roughly from $1$ in $2$ to in this case $1$ in $7$ per test).